# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8332

Tags: bitcoind

I get this error:

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8332
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1182:14)
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 8332 }
```

when I use this code:

```
var bitcoin = require('bitcoin');
var client = new bitcoin.Client({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8332,
    user: 'Rohit',
    pass: '12345'
});
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of your bitcoin.conf file (censoring any passwords as necessary)?

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! You can help the site by marking answers as accepted if they are correct and address the question so that the question does not remain as "unanswered".

Answer (score 1):

I hadn't started bitcored service ..that's why this error occurs
when I started, the error had gone

i followed these steps that given [here](https://bitcore.io/start)

Anyway thanks**

Comment: The link is dead. Can you please write steps here so links won't be used.

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin json rpc requires bitcoin core to actually start for it to work and won't work if it turn off